# Why did Shisui sacrifice himself?

Tags: naruto

Why did Shisui sacrifice himself? More importantly, why did he crush his eyes?

Is it because he wasn't strong enough to protect them from falling into the wrong hands? What made him think that Itachi could stop the revolt even when he knew he was stronger than Itachi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was made pretty clear when Itachi explains it to Naruto when he was Edo Tensei. 
Itachi and Shisui both new a Civil War was on the cards since Uchiha were plotting a Coup. Both having grown up in the era of great war didn't want it to come to that. Shisui tried to use his Genjutsu prowess on the village elders to stop the anhilation of Uchihas, but Danzo overpowered him and stole his eye. Shisui managed to get away but lost an eye. He didn't want any other power monger to get hold of his other Mangekyo Sharingan and thus entrusted it to Itachi, because he knew he believed in the same ideals. He left the village and faked his death.

Source: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shisui_Uchiha

On a smartphone. So will edit with proper citations of manga chapters later. Please take a look at Wikia. It should explain it more clearly

Edit 1: For those convinced he commited suicide

> Shisui wrote a suicide note telling his clan he cannot follow through with the coup d'etat, but his clan's narrow mindedness made them unable to understand this, believing he would even sacrifice innocent lives for the sake of the Uchiha Clan. The contents of the suicide note also made it appear as though he had crushed his eyes when jumping off a cliff into the Naka River to kill himself in order to prevent conflict from arising over his eyes within the clan. He, at the same time, was able to erase his existence, leaving no corpse behind.
>   Wiki Source: Chapter 550 pg11. Chapter 520 pg 15

Edit 2: I am not sure whats wrong with people, but they do not want to do their own research but will hold their beliefs and opinions as hard facts. I am open to different interpretations of said facts BUT don't refute the facts. [Here is the anime clip of Shisui giving his eye to Itachi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYwRU3B0Q7o) (Not that itachi killed him and took his eye)

Comment: He didn't faked his death. He committed suicide. Faked his death means he only pretend to die but is actually still alive.

Comment: Actually his body is never discovered, only his suicide note. We don't know when and If he died. Edited the answer to include the quote from wiki and its cited source pages from manga

Comment: We know he died because that's how Itachi got his Mangekyo Sharingan.

Comment: Umm... We see Shisui taking his eye out and giving it to Itachi. Not Shisui commiting suicude afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Story part related to it in the game "Naruto Shippuden : Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution", and if I remember well :

Danzô wanted to steal Shisui's eyes to use their power to prevent the coup d'etat from happening, because Shisui didn't want to use it against his own clan.
Danzô succeeded to steal one of Shisui's eyes, but Shisui managed to escape just after. He knew Danzô would do everything to get the other eye, so he chose to give it to Itachi (and so Danzô can't know where the 2nd eye is), and as he had no eyes anymore, I guess he thought that living in these conditions was meaningless and committed suicide.

Answer (score 0):

Shisui was actually poisoned by Danzo. In terms of strength Danzo would stand no  chance against Shisui if it came down to a 1 on 1 battle.